# H2Database - using mssql DATETIMEOFFSET data type

Tags: java, h2

I totally fail when i want use this data type. I get exception:

```
Unknown data type: "DATETIMEOFFSET"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.usr_user ALTER COLUMN next_password_change_date DATETIMEOFFSET [50004-196]
```

Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no `DATETIMEOFFSET` data type in h2 like in SQL server.
Reference: http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html

Way around that will be to choose a different date type e.g. `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.